# There is a way to protect my rest api from copy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I build an api according to REST methods in nodejs.

To get all my articles for example I make a get request to: `/api/articles`. to get one article `/api/articles/1`.

This is good when my website consume this data, its easy and makes my call from the client much easier.

But an hacker or another developer who familiar with REST, can basically steal all my data by just open devtools and see all my request to the api and browse into `/api/articles` or any similar entity.

There is a way to protect my data?

Comment: Authentication, rate limiting, there are many many ways.

Comment: I don't need and I won't the user to be loggedin, when I display the articles or others entities... I just don't want anybody steal my data...

Comment: You'll have to implement some authentication logic. That way you can login from the client, and store the resulting auth credentials on the client.Then whenever you make a request to `/api/articles` you'll have to include them, and check on the server-side that those credentials match with whats expected.

Comment: If it's on the internet, it *will* be found. That's just how the internet works.

Comment: I do authentication for those need to be authentication. but some data is public, but I afraid for someone to steal my public data..

Comment: @JonSud _public_ data can by definition not be stolen. It's public, it's available to everyone. If you have something in your public data that you don't want other people to find, then done include in your public data.

Comment: Let's say I work a lot to write the articles. and somebody just download all of them and post in his website... which is a problem for me..

Comment: @JonSud I'm not arguing with your motives. I'm simply saying that what you are attempting to do, is not doable. No matter the motives.

Comment: @JonSud In order to atleast make it a bit more difficult for a culprit,1) build the article page on the server and send a completed page to the client, 2) limit requests to only be accepted form your own domain, 3) look into the legal side of having someone steal your work, you can probably find a license that you can use that limits reuse of your content (however this will have no effect unless you are ready to pursue any offenders. Note that I'm not giving you legal advise.).

Comment: This made me think of the classic joke https://devrant.com/rants/945344/client-we-have-a-huge-security-problem-me-thinks-about-any-possible-vulnerabilit